# MySQL 100% CPU every 12-18 hours

Tags: mysql, database, windows, innodb, database-performance

I've inherited a Windows Server (2016) and we have a proprietary piece of software not written by me which uses a MySQL db. I am a novice w/ SQL.

There is client software that will connect to the server randomly throughout the day. Anywhere between 10 and 200 different computers will log into this server throughout the day depending on how busy we are.

We use a VPS w/ 4 virtual cores and 8GB of RAM and a 204GB local disk.

It seems like every 12-18 hours we have issues where our software will hang, Task Manager then shows 99-100% CPU usage for mysqld

It doesn't act normally again until I force quit the software and then restart the mysql service.

Here is the settings file I tracked down that was previously set up.

my.ini settings:

```
[client]
port=3306
[mysql]
no-beep=
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7\Data
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="xyz.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="xyz-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="xyz.err"
server-id=1
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"
max_connections=151
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=249M
thread_cache_size=10
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=486M
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_thread_concurrency=13
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=4M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=4161
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
```

Here's a pic of MySQLTuner for Windows and it's results:
[mysql_tuner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6j6N.png)

Just looking for some insight into what we can do here to help alleviate this issue. It appears we need to run OPTIMIZE to fix the fragmentation of the tables.

It also shows 23M selects with 0% caching.

The innodb data size / buffer pool is 687M/8M

Any help would be appreciated.

[EDIT]

I just ran the following command that I found in another thread:

```
SELECT CEILING(Total_InnoDB_Bytes*1.6/POWER(1024,3)) RIBPS FROM
(SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) Total_InnoDB_Bytes
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;
```

I got a value of 2 back, so I should probably set `innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G`?

`SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=2*1024*1024*1024;`
will be fine.  You have 8GB machine.  I will take a while for MySQL to dynamically get this in place.  Check in 30 minutes with `SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;`   to see if it has accomplished your dynamic request.

Here's what SHOW CREATE TABLE recipes looks like:

```
mysql> USE xyz; SHOW CREATE TABLE recipes;
Database changed
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| recipes | CREATE TABLE `recipes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `dname` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `descrpara` text NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `costperserving` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `batchsize` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `servname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Serving',
  `rectype` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `servweight` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `servflvol` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isapproved` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isapproved2` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tags` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `allrestr` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `numsides` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `utensils` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Again, I'm a super novice but could there be something where our my.ini file shows a default character set of utf8, but in this, it shows latin1?

I'll update these again after 24h

PasteBin links for

[SHOW GLOBAL STATUS](https://pastebin.com/gam4QmKq)

[SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES](https://pastebin.com/htzqcK3G)

[SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS](https://pastebin.com/tBZzDcXm)

---

MySQLTuner after >1 day uptime. This is also after changing innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M to 1G. Total RAM usage for mysqld has been about 1.25G since then.

```
MySQL Tuner 0.8.3 - Peter Chapman <peter@conglomo.co.nz>
Performing tests on localhost:3306 at Friday, 16 November 2018 6:13:41 AM
Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.24-log
Archive Engine Installed
Berkeley DB Engine Not Installed
Federated Engine Not Installed
InnoDB Engine Installed
ISAM Engine Not Installed
NDBCLUSTER Engine Not Installed
Data in InnoDB tables: 687M (Tables: 257)
Data in MyISAM tables: 6M (Tables: 32)
Total fragmented tables: 67
All database users have passwords assigned
Up for: 1d 10h 33m 15s (49M q [397.000 qps], 38K conn, TX: 43G, RX: 3G)
Reads / Writes: 99% / 1%
Total buffers: 1.0G global + 1.1M per thread (151 max threads)
Maximum possible memory usage: 1.2G (14% of installed RAM)
Slow queries: 1% (4/49M)
Highest usage of available connections: 26% (38/151)
Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/1.0M
Key buffer hit rate: 98% (630 cached / 9 reads)
Query cache efficiency: 0% (0 cached / 47M selects)
Query cache prunes per day: 0
Sorts requiring temporary tables: 1% (2K temp sorts / 377K sorts)
Joins performed without indexes: 13254
Temporary tables created on disk: 3% (2K on disk / 79K total)
Thread cache hit rate: 99% (41 created / 38K connections)
Table cache hit rate: 26% (2K open / 7K opened)
Open file limit used: 0% (10/6K)
Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (682 immediate / 682 locks)
InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 687.0M/1.0G
Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
Scan Completed at Friday, 16 November 2018 6:13:44 AM
```

[SHOW GLOBAL STATUS - > 1 day uptime](https://pastebin.com/Y1xU561J)

[SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES - > 1 day uptime](https://pastebin.com/SYVNMBJf)

Comment: Nope, if you see the mysql_tuner pic I linked, it's definitely 687M/8M. It actually used to run on linux but the programmer decided he wanted to run everything on Windows Server.

Comment: Run the `mysqladmin pr -vvv` command so you can view what queries are going on when this event happens. Could just be your software issuing a silly query that will take far too long to finish.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try to update once we hit >24 hours uptime.

Comment: You have the Slowlog turned on; what does it tell you?

Comment: We see a lot in the slowlog each day from what I'm seeing. Not all of them are this bad, but there are times when we'll see 20-50 query-times in a row over 300s. They look like this: # Time: 2018-11-14T01:05:09.554491Z
# User@Host: xyz[xyz] @ localhost [::1]  Id: 15877
# Query_time: 581.136648  Lock_time: 0.000024 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1542157509;
SELECT isapproved FROM recipes WHERE id=2939;

Comment: @sla_seth Please post results of SHOW CREATE TABLE recipes; into your original Question.  Is there daily maintenance going on at 1 AM?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to consider for immediate relief

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=1*1024*1024*1024
```

from your MySQL command prompt

will make a world of difference for you and possibly let you survive while other details are sorted out.

Change your my.ini [mysqld] section to 1G for your next stop/start services.

Comment: @sla_seth  SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=2*1024*1024*1024;  will be fine.  Change your my.ini for next stop/start of services, please.  MAKE this change now so the rest of your day is reasonable.  This is a DYNAMIC Global Variable.

Comment: Thank you @wilson-hauck, If we're currently at 75% RAM used out of 8GB, then will this still be reasonable?

Comment: @sla_seth You should be fine with 2G for innnodb_buffer_pool_size.

Comment: These are all good suggestions, but they will only help a little. Bang for the buck goes to tuning what's going on. I would check to see if things are stacking up first and then looking at the process_list. "SELECT r.trx_id waiting_trx_id,  r.trx_mysql_thread_id waiting_thread, r.trx_query waiting_query, b.trx_id blocking_trx_id,  b.trx_mysql_thread_id blocking_thread, b.trx_query blocking_query FROM  information_schema.innodb_lock_waits w INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx b  ON  b.trx_id = w.blocking_trx_id INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx r  ON  r.trx_id = w.requesting_trx_id;

Comment: @TGray  I am hoping sla_seth will post his observations on how much the suggestions have helped.  He has not been back here since Nov 18, 18.  Hoping he returns and shares net result so we know how he is doing at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Additional suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section
Rate Per Second=RPS

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G  # from 1G reported in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS of 11/16
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve CPU cycles every SECOND
thread_cache_size=100  # from 10 to increase threads_cached for increased performance
innodb_io_capacity=1600  # from 200 to allow higher IOPS 
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 63407
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M  # from 1M for ~ 30 minutes in RAM before WD
open_files_limit=8192  # from 6209 to reduce opened_files RPHour of 152
table_open_cache=3000  # from 2000 to reduce opened_tables RPHour of 258
query_cache_size=0  # from 1M to conserve RAM since QC is OFF
```

For additional assistance please view my profile, Network profile for contact info.

If you add a comment, please start with @wilsonhauck for me to be alerted by SO automatically.

Comment: @sla_seth Applied the Nov 19 suggestions?  Did they make a difference?

Comment: not yet. The original suggestions have made a huge improvement so far though. I'm still waiting on approval to make the rest of the changes. Thanks again!

Comment: @sla_seth If you can get permission for the next 9, you will be more AMAZED.  Good luck on getting approval, soon.

Comment: @sla_seth Wish there was a way I could help. Ask the person you are waiting on to please look at the Reviews posted on my web site.  Maybe that will have a positive impact.  Every day of delay is just more wasted time for every person using the software.